# Connect to web service with network credentials xamarin

Tags: c#, web-services, xamarin, xamarin.forms, asmx

I try connect my xamarin forms app with asmx web service.

I create DependencyServices and add service call here.

```
public string GetConferences()
{
using (service = new worksops())//my service
{
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredentials("username","password");
var conferencesjson = service.GetConferenceList();
return conferencesjson;
}

}
```

this code working perfect on wpf project with c# , but here in xamarin i get WebException "HTTP status 401: Unauthorized".

more infos :

inside in Responce i found System.NotImplementedException on the IsMutuallyAuthenticated.

Any ideas ??

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this:

```
service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";
```